# How to run tcl script inside other tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I have two tcl scripts. I want to run the second script when the first finished. How can I do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depends on what do you really mean.

One way is to write a third ("master") script which would do

```
source /the/path/to/the/first.tcl
source /the/path/to/the/second.tcl
```

Another way is to just add the second call to `source` from the above example to the bottom of the first script.

Amendment to the first approach: if the scripts to be executed are located in the same directory as the master script, an idiomatic way to `source` them is

```
set where [file dirname [info script]]
source [file join $where first.tcl]
source [file join $where second.tcl]
```

This way sourcing will work no matter what the current process's directory is and where the project directory is located.

Answer (score 10):

While this is generally a correct answer, because the question was not precisely formulated there are tons of ways to achieve the goal of running Tcl code from within Tcl.
I want to get into this in detail because understanding the execution of code is one major point in understanding Tcl itself.

## There is `source`

The `source` command should not be confound with executing scripts in a classical way, what I think the thread starter has asked.

The source command is like the "include" command in c/perl/php.
Languages like java or python on the other hand only have "import" mechanisms.

The difference is that those languages create a internal database of available packages, who are linked to the corresponding source/binary/bytecode files. By writing a import statement, linked source or bytecode or binary files are loaded. This allows more in-depth dependency management without writing additional code.
In Tcl this can be achieved with namespaces and the `package require` command.
Example:

Suppose you have this source.tcl:

```
proc foo {bar} {puts "baz"}
set BAM "BOO"
```

Now, you have your "master" script like you call it. I call it "main". It has the content:

```
set BAM {my important data}
source source.tcl
#also the function foo can now be used because the source reads the whole script
foo {wuz}
set BAM
#will output "BOO"
```

## The `exec` command

If you can live with additional overhead of starting a whole new interpreter instance you could also do:

```
set BAM {my important data}
exec tclsh source.tcl
#The variable BAM will not be modified. You can not use the function foo.
```

## The `eval` command

The command `eval` can evaluate a string or a list (in Tcl everything is a string) like it would be programmed code.
You would have to load the complete source file to a string. And then use `eval`, to evaluate the code within a separate scope, to not overwrite stuff in your main source file.

```
set fp [open "somefile" r]
set code_string [read $fp]
close $fp
eval $code_string
```

Comment: Two other major routes for evaluating a piece of code: child interpreters, and the thread package. And then there's `namespace eval` and `uplevel` (but they're very much like `eval` except in that they change what exact context they evaluate within) and arguably many other commands besides.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use source to run the 2nd script.

```
source "/tmp/whatever.tcl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible working example I could find:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ tclsh main.tcl 
hello world
7
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ cat main.tcl 
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/api

package require weather 1.0



tutstack::hello

set A 3
set B 4

puts [tutstack::sum $A $B]


#puts [tutstack::hello "fred"]



thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ cat api/weather.tcl 
package provide weather  1.0
package require Tcl      8.5

namespace eval ::tutstack {
}

proc ::tutstack::hello {} {
    puts "hello world"
}


proc ::tutstack::sum {arg1 arg2} {
    set x [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}];
    return $x
}

proc ::tutstack::helloWorld {arg1} {
    return "hello plus arg"
}
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ cat api/pkgIndex.tcl 
# Tcl package index file, version 1.1
# This file is generated by the "pkg_mkIndex" command
# and sourced either when an application starts up or
# by a "package unknown" script.  It invokes the
# "package ifneeded" command to set up package-related
# information so that packages will be loaded automatically
# in response to "package require" commands.  When this
# script is sourced, the variable $dir must contain the
# full path name of this file's directory.

package ifneeded weather 1.0 [list source [file join $dir weather.tcl]]
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$
```